# how do I replace outliers with groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Hi this is my (toy) data :

```
data = {'p1': [100., 101, 102, 100, 100],
        'p2': [100., 99., 98., 100., 100],
        'p3': [1000., 1000., 100., 1000., 1000]
        }
df = (pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.bdate_range(start='20100101', periods=5))
      .stack()
      .reset_index()
      .rename(columns={'level_0': 'date', 'level_1': 'type', 0: 'price'})
      .sort_values('date')
      )
df['perf'] = df.groupby('type')['price'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change(1))
df.sort_values('type')
```

with look like that :

```
0   2010-01-01  p1  100.0   NaN
3   2010-01-04  p1  101.0   0.010000
6   2010-01-05  p1  102.0   0.009901
9   2010-01-06  p1  100.0   -0.019608
12  2010-01-07  p1  100.0   0.000000
1   2010-01-01  p2  100.0   NaN
4   2010-01-04  p2  99.0    -0.010000
7   2010-01-05  p2  98.0    -0.010101
10  2010-01-06  p2  100.0   0.020408
13  2010-01-07  p2  100.0   0.000000
2   2010-01-01  p3  1000.0  NaN
5   2010-01-04  p3  1000.0  0.000000
8   2010-01-05  p3  100.0   -0.900000  -> outlier
11  2010-01-06  p3  1000.0  9.000000.  -> outlier
14  2010-01-07  p3  1000.0  0.000000
```

I would like to replace these (2) values with the mean or median of perf columns without these data. I mean I calculate (with the previous help) :

```
# perf for each type 
df['perf'] = df.groupby('type')['price'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change(1))

# Outliers & replace value with median by date 
outliers = df.groupby('type')['price'].apply(lambda x: (x.pct_change(1).abs() >= 0.5))
df.loc[outliers, "perf"] = (df[~outliers]
                            .groupby('date')
                            .median()
                            .loc[df.loc[outliers, "date"], "perf"]
                            .values
                            )

df['price2'] = (df.groupby('type')['price'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0])).mul(df.groupby('type')['perf'].apply(lambda x: (1+x).cumprod()), fill_value=1) 
# New price with the same initial value of the prices but with perf corrected 

df.sort_values('type')
```

but at the end it is not "nice". Is there a way to improve my code with functions for example ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
# Filter for outliers
outliers = df['perf'].abs() >= 0.5

# Create DataFrame for the mean of each date
dt_mean = df.groupby('date')['perf'].mean().to_frame().copy()

# Reset index
dt_mean.reset_index(inplace=True) 

# Set outliers equal to merger of outliers and mean DataFrame
df.loc[outliers,'perf'] = list(pd.merge(df.loc[outliers, ['date', 'type', 'price']],dt_mean, on='date')['perf'])

    date       type price   perf
0   2010-01-01  p1  100.0   NaN
1   2010-01-01  p2  100.0   NaN
2   2010-01-01  p3  1000.0  NaN
3   2010-01-04  p1  101.0   0.010000
4   2010-01-04  p2  99.0    -0.010000
5   2010-01-04  p3  1000.0  0.000000
6   2010-01-05  p1  102.0   0.009901
7   2010-01-05  p2  98.0    -0.010101
8   2010-01-05  p3  100.0   -0.300067
9   2010-01-06  p1  100.0   -0.019608
10  2010-01-06  p2  100.0   0.020408
11  2010-01-06  p3  1000.0  3.000267
12  2010-01-07  p1  100.0   0.000000
13  2010-01-07  p2  100.0   0.000000
14  2010-01-07  p3  1000.0  0.000000
```

Comment: It is not precisely what I need. I would like to replace the outliers with the average on each date that's why I used ```df[~outliers].groupby('date').mean()```. It is these values that I would like to replace inside my data (the ```groupby```in my code are important)

Answer (score 0):

How about performing a direct `.loc[]` query on the mean dataframe?

```
outliers = df.groupby('type')['price'].apply(lambda x: (x.pct_change(1).abs() >= 0.5))
df_mean = df[~outliers].groupby('date').mean()

fill_values = df_mean.loc[df.loc[outliers, "date"], "perf"].values
df.loc[outliers, "perf"] = fill_values  # broadcast
df.sort_values('type')
Out[114]: 
         date type   price      perf
0  2010-01-01   p1   100.0       NaN
3  2010-01-04   p1   101.0  0.010000
6  2010-01-05   p1   102.0  0.009901
9  2010-01-06   p1   100.0 -0.019608
12 2010-01-07   p1   100.0  0.000000
1  2010-01-01   p2   100.0       NaN
4  2010-01-04   p2    99.0 -0.010000
7  2010-01-05   p2    98.0 -0.010101
10 2010-01-06   p2   100.0  0.020408
13 2010-01-07   p2   100.0  0.000000
2  2010-01-01   p3  1000.0       NaN
5  2010-01-04   p3  1000.0  0.000000
8  2010-01-05   p3   100.0 -0.000100  <- replaced by mean
11 2010-01-06   p3  1000.0  0.000400  <- replaced by mean
14 2010-01-07   p3  1000.0  0.000000
```

Note that your mean value by date (`df_mean`) is already indexed by `date`, and it doesn't seem possible to avoid its creation. So just make use of its date index directly.

```
df_mean  
Out[115]: 
            price    perf
date                     
2010-01-01  400.0     NaN
2010-01-04  400.0  0.0000
2010-01-05  100.0 -0.0001
2010-01-06  100.0  0.0004
2010-01-07  400.0  0.0000
```